# How do I use Selenium Webdriver on headless Chrome?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless-browser

I'm learning to use Selenium for basic things like taking a screenshot, scraping, and testing and would like to use it with headless Chrome, which is now stable as of Chrome 59.

I have been able to take a screenshot using the 'selenium-webdriver' gem and chromedriver, but not headless.

Here is the ruby script that I am running which hangs after starting to initialize the driver

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :debug
p 'initializing driver'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, switches: %w[--headless --disable-gpu --screenshot --hide-scrollbars]
p 'navigating to Google'
driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"  
driver.save_screenshot("./screen.png")
driver.quit
```

and the output  from the logs:

```
:> ruby rubytest.rb
"initializing driver"
2017-06-07 15:55:43 DEBUG Selenium Executing Process 

["/Users/name/Documents/scrapings/python/env/bin/chromedriver", "--port=9515"]
2017-06-07 15:55:43 DEBUG Selenium polling for socket on ["127.0.0.1", 9515]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.29.461585 (0be2cd95f834e9ee7c46bcc7cf405b483f5ae83b) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
2017-06-07 15:55:43 INFO Selenium -> POST session
2017-06-07 15:55:43 INFO Selenium    >>> http://127.0.0.1:9515/session | {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","version":"","platform":"ANY","javascriptEnabled":true,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":false,"nativeEvents":false,"rotatable":false,"chromeOptions":{"args":["--headless","--disable-gpu","--screenshot","--hide-scrollbars"]}}}
2017-06-07 15:55:43 DEBUG Selenium      > {"Accept"=>"application/json", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "Content-Length"=>"284"}
[RUBY BACKTRACE TO DRIVER INITIALIZATION]
```

I have tried using the JavaScript and Python drivers with similar code and nothing works. When I try this with Python, the error message is

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461585 (0be2cd95f834e9ee7c46bcc7cf405b483f5ae83b),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.5 x86_64)
```

Comment: Is this of use? https://medium.com/@CukeHub/headless-chrome-with-ruby-cucumber-selenium-abf6da437fd9

Comment: Yes, it was of some use, thank you. Passing the `--headless` argument through desired_capabilities allowed me to navigate and select elements headlessly; however, this method still does not give a screenshot like normal 'non-headless' Chrome.

Comment: I just found a nice little [link](https://sermoa.wordpress.com/2013/10/24/getting-chromedriver-to-work-with-ruby-selenium-webdriver-under-osx-mavericks/) that deals with the same/similar problem.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Ruby. Browser launches in headless mode OK, but resulting screenshot is empty.
This works fine for me in Python and JavaScript.

Answer (score 12):

I found [this blog post](https://intoli.com/blog/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome-in-ruby/) useful for setting up headless chrome with selenium in ruby

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

# configure the driver to run in headless mode
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options

driver.navigate.to "https://www.google.com"

# resize the window and take a screenshot
driver.manage.window.resize_to(800, 800)
driver.save_screenshot "screenshot.png"
```

Answer (score 2):

Managed to work through this in the end via various docs, blog posts and gists.

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("desiredCapabilities" => {"takesScreenshot" => true}, "chromeOptions" => {"binary" => "/Applications/Google Chrome Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Canary"})

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps, switches: %w[--headless --no-sandbox --disable-gpu --remote-debugin-port=9222 --screen-size=1200x800]
```

You need to use a very recent version of Chrome (I'm using Canary) and tell Selenium the path to the binary. You also need to set the desired capabilities for 'takesScreenshot' to true.

Comment: Note for anyone running things inside a Docker container, you'll need to replace element.send_keys() with this util function:

def send_keys(d, el, str)
 d.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("value", arguments[1])', el, str)
end

Use it like so: send_keys(driver, searchElement, "WebDriver")

Comment: I'm on Chrome 59 which is the most recent version, andI'm still getting a blank screenshot. Also, is there a reason that you have desiredCapabilities nested twice?

Comment: Good question, and in fact you're right we can clean this up like so:

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("desiredCapabilities" => {"takesScreenshot" => true}, "chromeOptions" => {"binary" => "/Applications/Google Chrome Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Canary", "args" => ["--headless", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu", "--remote-debugin-port=9222", "--screen-size=1200x800"]})

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps

Comment: Not sure why screenshots don't work with v59, but you can download Canary (v61) here: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html

Hopefully whatever fixes are in v61 will filter into the stable release sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a [blog post](https://www.lucascaton.com.br/2017/06/22/how-to-run-your-feature-specs-using-capybara-and-headless-chrome/) about how to do it. Summing up:

1) Make sure you have **Chrome** version **57+** on Linux, **59+** on macOS or **60+** on Windows;

2) Add/update the gem `selenium-webdriver`;

3) Make sure you’re using **ChromeDriver** version 2.30 or higher;

4) Add the following **driver** to your `spec_helper.rb` or `rails_helper.rb`:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app, browser: :chrome,
    options: Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: %w[headless disable-gpu])
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```